# Argument "never_split" not working on bert tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I used the `never_split` option and tried to retain some tokens. But the tokenizer still divide them into wordpieces.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', never_split=['lol'])
tokenizer.tokenize("lol That's funny")
['lo', '##l', 'that', "'", 's', 'funny']
```

Do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call this a bug or at least not good documented. The `never_split` argument is only considered when you use the BasicTokenizer (which is part of the BertTokenizer).

You are calling the tokenize function from your specific model (bert-base-uncased) and this considers **only** his vocabulary (as I would expect). In order to prevent splitting of certain tokens, they must be part of the vocabulary (you can extend the vocabulary with the method [add_tokens](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.add_tokens)).

I think the example below shows what I am trying to say:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

text = "lol That's funny lool"

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', never_split=['lol'])
#what you are doing
print(tokenizer.tokenize(text))

#how it is currently working
print(tokenizer.basic_tokenizer.tokenize(text))

#how you should do it
tokenizer.add_tokens('lol')
print(tokenizer.tokenize(text))
```

Output:

```
['lo', '##l', 'that', "'", 's', 'funny', 'lo', '##ol']
['lol', 'that', "'", 's', 'funny', 'lool']
['lol', 'that', "'", 's', 'funny', 'lo', '##ol']
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! One thing I noticed is that once you used ```add_tokens``` option, the vocabluary size increases. So I tried to change the embedding size by using ```resize_token_embeddings```. However, this only works for pytorch model, but not for any TF ones (such as TFBertModel).

Comment: Your observation is correct. It is currently not on the roadmap of Huggingface to implement this (check [#1838](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1838)).

Comment: Got it. Seems the only way is to import my own vocab. That limits to only <1k tokens.

Comment: You won't benefit from the pretrained weights when you replace the bert vocabulary with  your own vocabulary. Each item of the Bert vocabulary belongs to a certain embedding weight.

Comment: True. But if you use ```add_tokens```, how will the new tokens be reflected in the embedding layers? I just tried without editing ```resize_token_embeddings```. The model still runs, I suppose the new tokens will just be ignored in the embedding since it's added at the end of vocab?

Comment: New tokens will get random weights. The problem with your approach is, that the first, second, and third entry of the embedding layer represent a certain word (lets say A,B,C).  When you now use your own vocabulary, you will probably change the order (e.g. first three entries of your vocab are C,D,A). I.e. C gets the weights of A, D gets the weights of B, and A gets the weights of C. Of course it is working, but the resuts will be different from a model with `add_tokens` and `resize`.